# Display a count of records that are not nulls

Tags: reporting-services

Most of the records in the report in the field VOID are nulls (no display)

I do not know where to begin, so there is nothing to show that i have tried.

How do i present a summary count of records in the report that are not nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a few things...

1. The VOID field is text.
2. The "*nulls*" are against each record and not the result of a
   matrix/pivot where in fact no record exists in your dataset.
3. You Dataset is called `myDataSet`

To count all the null or empty instances you can use something like this

```
=SUM(IIF(LEN(TRIM(Fields!VOID.Value)) > 0 , 1, 0), "myDataSet")
```

This takes the content of the VOID field, TRIMs it (this will remove spaces, it's all spaces it will return an empty string). Then be check the LEN of this. If it's not zero then return 1, else return 0. Then SUM all the results within the scope of the dataset called `myDataSet`

Comment: PERFECT ANSWER - thank you!!